# Picture and text scraping with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using python, how would you go about scraping both pictures and text from a website.  For example say I wanted to scrape both the pictures and the text [here](http://washingtondc.craigslist.org/apa/), what python tools/libraries would I use?  Any tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

Please never use regular expressions, it's not made for parsing html.

Normally I make use of the following combination of tools:

- requests module
- lxml.html
- beautifulsoup4 to detect the website encoding

A approach would look like this and I hope you get the idea (The code just illustrated the concept, not tested, won't work):

```
import lxml.html
import requests
from cssselect import HTMLTranslator, SelectorError
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit

# first do the http request with requests module like
r = requests.get('http://example.com')
html = r.read()

# Try to parse/decode the HTML result with lxml and beautifoulsoup4
try:
    doc = UnicodeDammit(html, is_html=True)
    parser = lxml.html.HTMLParser(encoding=doc.declared_html_encoding)
    dom = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html, parser=parser)
    dom.resolve_base_href()
except Exception as e:
    print('Some error occured while lxml tried to parse: {}'.format(e.msg))
    return False

# Try to extract all data that we are interested in with CSS selectors!
try:
    results = dom.xpath(HTMLTranslator().css_to_xpath('some css selector to target the DOM'))
    for e in results:
        # access elements like
        print(e.get('href')) # access href attribute
        print(e.text_content()) # the content as text
        # or process further
        found = e.xpath(HTMLTranslator().css_to_xpath('h3.r > a:first-child'))
except Exception as e:
    print(e.__cause__)
```

Answer (score 0):

[requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests), [scrapy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Scrapy), and [BeatidulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup).

Scrapy is optional, but requests are becoming nonofficial standard, and I haven't seen bettern parsing tool than BS.

Comment: BS is relatively slow and pretty buggy--even BS4

Comment: Do you know another XML manipulation framework with this level ob abstraction? If so, please share, I would be personally interested, and it would enhance answer to this question ;)

Comment: As the other answer mentioned, lxml is entirely sufficient now, and can parse pages that choke BS. I'm willing to give up a bit of abstraction and get my hands dirty with XPath moonspeak if it means a page will parse

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - isn't BS4 just a facade for other low-level but high-speed XML parsers (like mentioned lxml)? I mean, this is what they say at the top of their homepage. Why would BS4 choke on something that lxml could parse if it would use lxml? I have never really seen situation like you've described...

Comment: One of BS's selling points (figuratively) back in the 2000s was actually that it could parse pages that were too messy for lxml to handle. BS' webpage still contains this distinction: "Valuable data that was once locked up in poorly-designed websites is now within your reach." BS isn't just a wrapper for lxml--you can use other parsers like python's very slow built-in html parser. I don't know why BS' lxml flavor couldn't handle a webpage, but lxml could just fine.